# hex decimals in preg expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

To replace non-breaking space with a normal space:

```
preg_replace('/\xA0/u', ' ', $value);
```

But in a class the hex decimal is already declared in a constant. How to use this constant in the pattern?

```
const NBSP = "\xA0";

preg_replace('/'.self::NBSP.'/u', ' ', $value);
```

Comment: In utf8 (since you use the u modifier), the non-breaking space is encoded with two bytes: c2 a0.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the backslash:

```
const NBSP = "\\xA0";
```

Example (with `*` char, to be more visible):

```
class Foo 
{
    const NBSP = "\\xA0";
    
    public function __construct($value)
    {
        var_dump(preg_replace('/' . self::NBSP . '/u', '*', $value));
    }
}

new Foo("foo bar"); // (contain a non-breaking space - Not rendered here)
new Foo("foo\xc2\xa0bar"); // (hexa form)
```

Output :

```
string(7) "foo*bar"
string(7) "foo*bar"
```

[demo (3v4l.org)](https://3v4l.org/tFIUa)

Comment: Does it solve your issue @clarkk?